# To use a Scalar function or Table valued function,in sql server to determine the best

Tags: sql-server

I am using `Sql-server 2012`

My table definition is:

```
create table products1(pid int,pnm varchar(10),oid int foreign key references orders1(oid))

create table orders1(oid int primary key,onm varchar(10),odt date)

insert into products1 values(1,'ABC',1),(2,'DEF',2)

insert into orders1 values(1,'QTY','2013-04-27'),(2,'PROD','2015-04-29')

create function dbo.udf_getmaxdt(@a date)
returns date
as
begin
select @a=max(o.odt) from orders1 o inner join products1 p on o.oid=p.pid
return @a
end


create function dbo.udf_getmaxdt(@a date)
returns TABLE 
as
RETURN
(
select @a=max(o.odt) from orders1 o inner join products1 p on o.oid=p.pid
)
end
```

The syntax might be wrong but I am on the task to determine the best of the 2 types of function.

But aint able to tell which one,could you help me on this?

regards,
Chio

Comment: Just remember UDF's are often unintended performance killers. If you needlessly create and use a UDF you might find that it doesn't scale and when you have 100x as many records you have a performance issue that's difficult to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is scalar function

The second one is inline table valued UDF

The second one has a pattern which you can recognize:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_geo_calcDistance]
(
    ...
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN  SELECT ...
```

The second one  , when inlined with a query , will cause the query not to be referenced as an outside query but as an inline query , which will be mush faster

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your provided definition of table-valued function has incorrect syntax (you're not returning resultset there), it is impossible to state "scalar function is better than table-valued" (or vice versa) - because this statement like "apples are better than cars".

It is two absolutely different types of functions:

- table-valued function returns result of some query, it can be multiple rows in this resultset.
- scalar function returns only one scalar value.

So it's up to you - what should you use in each particular case.

There are some tricks using inline table-valued functions as scalar ones (by returning single row of data containing single value), and this makes sense in some cases (mostly by eliminating bottlenecks in performance optimization), but it should not be considered as some "universal recipe" for any use-case.